# Android Firebase ListView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Working on an Android Project using Firebase.

The project is to let users check in and display all logs in a table view.

I have set up the firebase database as follows:

[image: Firebase image]

I can't get the entries to show in the table view?
I would like to show the following items per list item:

- userCheckIn
- username
- userLocation

My code:

```
    private ListView mListView;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabse;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String Date;
    Calendar calendar;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.database_list_view);
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
        mDatabse = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CheckInOut").child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child(Date).child("userCheckIn");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDatabse.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String string = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                arrayList.add(string);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

I would appreciate any support possible.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, move the declaration of your `ArrayList` and `ArrayAdapter` inside `onChildAdded()` method. You need also to set the adapter inside `onChildAdded()` method because this method has an asynchronous behaviour. This means that if you are trying to set the adapter outside `onChildAdded()` method it will always be empty because at that time you haven't got all the data from the database. So all operation must take place inside that method.

I recomand you also to use [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android). It will handle all the events for you. If want to read more about how you can get the data outside an asynchronous method, take a look at my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774).